# Embedded Jetty 9 Logging with Logback

Tags: jetty, slf4j, logback

I use [jetty](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/) in a maven project and logging is already in place using slf4j and logback. 
Hence, I have a logback.xml where I configure logging and it works so far (format, setting levels for my project and libraries, ...).

However, now that I added jetty in the pom.xml as a dependency, I get tons of new DEBUG logs which I do not want to see (usually).

How can I set the log level for jetty to a higher level?

At the beginning, jetty reports that it recognized slf4j:

```
13:08:57 [main]      [DEBUG] log - Logging to Logger[org.eclipse.jetty.util.log] via org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Slf4jLog
```

In my logback.xml, I tried to mute jetty as follows, but it does not work:

```
<logger name="org.eclipse.jetty" level="INFO" />
```

This does the trick for other libraries that I use.

I read the [jetty documentation regarding logging](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/configuring-logging.html), but they only document the use of standalone jetty - unfortunately, I was not able to adapt it for the embedded use case.

Comment: Use this link to config jetty logback: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67356061

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found the answer myself - it is slightly embarrassing.
The issue is that there are two configuration files for logging: logback.xml and logback-test.xml.

I did not adjust the level of the logger in logback-test.xml which is used during development in a maven project.
The logback.xml configuration, on the other hand, is used when a package is built, e.g. in production use.

From the [logback documentation](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html):

> If you are using Maven and if you place the logback-test.xml under the
>   src/test/resources folder, Maven will ensure that it won't be included
>   in the artifact produced. Thus, you can use a different configuration
>   file, namely logback-test.xml during testing, and another file,
>   namely, logback.xml, in production.

Due to lack of experiences with logback and maven, I did not know this.

To conclude:
Adding the following to the logback-test.xml solves my issue:

```
<logger name="org.eclipse.jetty" level="INFO" />
```