# Unable to make jetty use logback for logging

Tags: java, amazon-ec2, jetty, logback

I followed [this page](http://pietervogelaar.nl/ubuntu-12-04-install-jetty-9) to install jetty on a Amazon EC2 instance of mine (Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS). Jetty is running. However, I can't make it use logback for logging. Below are relevant information. What did I do wrong here?

**service check**

```
$ service jetty check
Checking arguments to Jetty:
START_INI      =  /opt/jetty/start.ini
START_D        =  /opt/jetty/start.d
JETTY_HOME     =  /opt/jetty
JETTY_BASE     =  /opt/jetty
JETTY_CONF     =  /opt/jetty/etc/jetty.conf
JETTY_PID      =  /tmp/jetty.pid
JETTY_START    =  /opt/jetty/start.jar
JETTY_LOGS     =  /opt/jetty/logs
JETTY_STATE    =  /opt/jetty/jetty.state
CLASSPATH      =
JAVA           =  /usr/bin/java
JAVA_OPTIONS   =  -Djetty.logs=/opt/jetty/logs -Djetty.home=/opt/jetty -Djetty.base=/opt/jetty -Djava.io.tmpdir=/tmp
JETTY_ARGS     =  jetty.state=/opt/jetty/jetty.state jetty-started.xml
RUN_CMD        =  /usr/bin/java -Djetty.logs=/opt/jetty/logs -Djetty.home=/opt/jetty -Djetty.base=/opt/jetty -Djava.io.tmpdir=/tmp -jar /opt/jetty/start.jar jetty.state=/opt/jetty/jetty.state jetty-started.xml
```

**/etc/default/jetty**

```
$ cat /etc/default/jetty
# Defaults for jetty see /etc/init.d/jetty for more

# change to 0 to allow Jetty to start
NO_START=0

# change to 'no' or uncomment to use the default setting in /etc/default/rcS
VERBOSE=yes

# Run Jetty as this user ID (default: jetty)
# Set this to an empty string to prevent Jetty from starting automatically
JETTY_USER=jetty

# Listen to connections from this network host
# Use 0.0.0.0 as host to accept all connections.
# Uncomment to restrict access to localhost
JETTY_HOST=0.0.0.0

# The network port used by Jetty
JETTY_PORT=8080

# Timeout in seconds for the shutdown of all webapps
JETTY_SHUTDOWN=30

# Additional arguments to pass to Jetty
#JETTY_ARGS=

# Extra options to pass to the JVM
#JAVA_OPTIONS="-Xmx256m -Djava.awt.headless=true -Djava.library.path=/usr/lib"

# Home of Java installation.
JAVA=/usr/bin/java
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64
JETTY_HOME=/opt/jetty

# The first existing directory is used for JAVA_HOME (if JAVA_HOME is not
# defined in /etc/default/jetty). Should contain a list of space separated directories.
#JDK_DIRS="/usr/lib/jvm/default-java /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun"

# Java compiler to use for translating JavaServer Pages (JSPs). You can use all
# compilers that are accepted by Ant's build.compiler property.
#JSP_COMPILER=jikes

# Jetty uses a directory to store temporary files like unpacked webapps
#JETTY_TMP=/var/cache/jetty

# Jetty uses a config file to setup its boot classpath
#JETTY_START_CONFIG=/etc/jetty/start.config

# Default for number of days to keep old log files in /var/log/jetty/
#LOGFILE_DAYS=14
```

**/opt/jetty/etc/jetty.conf**

```
$ cat /opt/jetty/etc/jetty.conf
# ========================================================
# jetty.conf Configuration for jetty.sh script
# --------------------------------------------------------
# This file is used by the jetty.sh script to provide
# extra configuration arguments for the start.jar command
# created by that script.
#
# Each line in this file becomes an arguement to start.jar
# in addition to those found in the start.ini file
# =======================================================
#jetty-logging.xml
jetty-started.xml
```

**/opt/jetty/modules/logging.mod**

```
$ cat /opt/jetty/modules/logging.mod
#
# Jetty std err/out logging
#

[name]
logging

[files]
logs/

[lib]
lib/logging/*.jar
resources/

[ini-template]
## Logging Configuration
# Configure jetty logging for default internal behavior STDERR output
# -Dorg.eclipse.jetty.util.log.class=org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.StdErrLog

# Configure jetty logging for slf4j
-Dorg.eclipse.jetty.util.log.class=org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Slf4jLog

# Configure jetty logging for java.util.logging
# -Dorg.eclipse.jetty.util.log.class=org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.JavaUtilLog

# STDERR / STDOUT Logging
# Number of days to retain logs
# jetty.log.retain=90
# Directory for logging output
# Either a path relative to ${jetty.base} or an absolute path
# jetty.logs=logs
```

**/opt/jetty/resources/logback.xml**

```
$ cat /opt/jetty/resources/logback.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <!-- Insert the current time formatted as "yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmss" under
       the key "bySecond" into the logger context. This value will be
       available to all subsequent configuration elements. -->
    <timestamp key="bySecond" datePattern="yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmss"/>

    <!-- console appender -->
    <appender name="CONSOLE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{100} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>/opt/jetty/logs/server.log</file>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <!-- daily rollover -->
            <fileNamePattern>/opt/jetty/logs/server.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</fileNamePattern>

            <!-- keep 30 days' worth of history -->
            <maxHistory>30</maxHistory>
        </rollingPolicy>

        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{100} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <logger name="org.eclipse.jetty" level="INFO"/>
    <logger name="org.springframework" level="INFO"/>
    <logger name="org.apache" level="INFO"/>

    <root level="DEBUG">
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
        <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
    </root>

</configuration>
```

**/opt/jetty/start.ini**

```
$ cat /opt/jetty/start.ini
#===========================================================
# Jetty Startup
#
# Starting Jetty from this {jetty.home} is not recommended.
#
# A proper {jetty.base} directory should be configured, instead
# of making changes to this {jetty.home} directory.
#
# See documentation about {jetty.base} at
# http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/startup.html
#
# A demo-base directory has been provided as an example of
# this sort of setup.
#
# $ cd demo-base
# $ java -jar ../start.jar
#
#===========================================================

# To disable the warning message, comment the following line
--module=home-base-warning


# ---------------------------------------
# Module: server
--module=server
##
## Server Threading Configuration
##
# minimum number of threads
threads.min=10
# maximum number of threads
threads.max=200
# thread idle timeout in milliseconds
threads.timeout=60000
# buffer size for output
jetty.output.buffer.size=32768
# request header buffer size
jetty.request.header.size=8192
# response header buffer size
jetty.response.header.size=8192
# should jetty send the server version header?
jetty.send.server.version=true
# should jetty send the date header?
jetty.send.date.header=false
# What host to listen on (leave commented to listen on all interfaces)
#jetty.host=0.0.0.0
# Dump the state of the Jetty server, components, and webapps after startup
jetty.dump.start=false
# Dump the state of the Jetty server, before stop
jetty.dump.stop=false
# Enable delayed dispatch optimisation
jetty.delayDispatchUntilContent=false

# ---------------------------------------
# Module: deploy
--module=deploy
## DeployManager configuration
# Monitored Directory name (relative to jetty.base)
# jetty.deploy.monitoredDirName=webapps


# ---------------------------------------
# Module: websocket
--module=websocket

# ---------------------------------------
# Module: ext
--module=ext

# ---------------------------------------
# Module: resources
--module=resources

# ---------------------------------------
# Module: jsp
--module=jsp
# JSP Configuration

# Select JSP implementation, choices are
#   glassfish : The reference implementation
#               default in jetty <= 9.1
#   apache    : The apache version
#               default jetty >= 9.2
jsp-impl=apache

# To use a non-jdk compiler for JSP compilation when using glassfish uncomment next line
# -Dorg.apache.jasper.compiler.disablejsr199=true

# ---------------------------------------
# Module: jstl
--module=jstl
# JSTL Configuration
# The glassfish jsp-impl includes JSTL by default and this module
# is not required to activate it.
# The apache jsp-impl does not include JSTL by default and this module
# is required to put JSTL on the container classpath


#
# Initialize module logging
#
--module=logging

# ---------------------------------------
# Module: http
--module=http
### HTTP Connector Configuration
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true

## HTTP port to listen on
jetty.port=8080

## HTTP idle timeout in milliseconds
http.timeout=30000

## HTTP Socket.soLingerTime in seconds. (-1 to disable)
# http.soLingerTime=-1

## Parameters to control the number and priority of acceptors and selectors
# http.selectors=1
# http.acceptors=1
# http.selectorPriorityDelta=0
# http.acceptorPriorityDelta=0
```

Answer (score 1):

Run the following command and **Jetty** do all the things:

```
[my-base]$ java -jar ../start.jar --add-to-start=logging-logback
```

---

**More configuration:** https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/jetty-9/index.html#configuring-logging

Answer (score 0):

First (and most important) don't change, edit, modify, add, remove, delete, mangle, rename, touch, etc anything in `${jetty.home}`

That is your jetty-distribution directory, its not meant to be changed, unpack it, then leave it alone.

It even tells you this when you startup!

```
2015-05-06 06:34:58.838:WARN:oejs.HomeBaseWarning:main: This instance of Jetty is not
running from a separate {jetty.base} directory, this is not recommended.  
See documentation at http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/startup.html
2015-05-06 06:34:58.959:INFO:oejs.Server:main: jetty-9.2.10.v20150310
```

**To fix this:**

Start by creating a new directory somewhere (anywhere) this will become your `${jetty.base}`

The `${jetty.base}` directory is where you configure your instance of a running Jetty.

The documentation has instructions on 3 different configurations for logback in a `${jetty.base}`

- [Just Logback](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/example-logging-logback.html)
- [Capturing all logging events on the server side from log4j, commons-logging, slf4j, jetty log, and java.util.logging and routing them to Logback](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/example-slf4j-multiple-loggers.html)
- [Forcing centralized logging of all logging, even those produced in webapps, to a single logback configuration](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/example-logging-logback-centralized.html)

If you follow those directions, you'll wind up with:

- a `${jetty.base}` that has a `start.ini` for you
- the libraries you'll need in `${jetty.base}/lib/logging`
- an overridden `${jetty.base}/modules/logging.mod`
- the logback configuration in `${jetty.base}/resources/logback.xml`
- the jetty logging configuration in `${jetty.base}/resources/jetty-logging.properties`

From here you setup the rest of the modules you'll need in `${jetty.base}/start.ini` along with your webapps and other bits and bobs you'll need (never once editing `${jetty.home}`)

Finally, you'll edit your `/etc/default/jetty` to add a `JETTY_BASE` that points to this directory.

To test if this `${jetty.base}` configuration makes sense, you'll use the command line.

CD into your new `${jetty.base}` and run

```
[mybase]$ java -jar /path/to/jetty-dist/start.jar
```

That will start up that configuration as a normal process (not a service), from which you'll be able to see if the configuration is behaving the way you need it to.

Comment: Thanks, Joakim. I created /opt/jetty/base and defined JETTY_BASE=/opt/jetty/base in /etc/default/jetty per your advice. However, it is still not working. I can still a new start.log created under /opt/jetty/base/logs. However, the expected server.log is still not there. I suspect I must have made incorrect configs somewhere, but I just can't find it. Any suggestions?

Comment: start.log is not part of the server logging infrastructure, that's part of the bootstrap that actually starts jetty, something that occurs before the server logging has initialized.  Test the configuration directly, as a normal process, like the answer says.  Then test it as a service.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by following the official example: http://eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/example-logging-logback-centralized.html. The actual steps are quite similar to what Joakim mentioned in his answer.

These are basically the commands I used:

```
[base]$ mkdir modules
[base]$ cd modules
[modules]$ curl -O https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jetty-project/logging-modules/master/capture-all/logging.mod
[modules]$ curl -O https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jetty-project/logging-modules/master/centralized/webapp-logging.mod
[modules]$ cd ..
[base]$ java -jar /opt/jetty/start.jar --add-to-start=logging,webapp-logging
```